# ArcGIS Pro: dragging lyr-file from folder in project creates 20 missing data sources

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, layer-file, data-source

I dragged "Fastighetskartan.lyr" into the map. It now shows up missing 20 data sources - even though the data source is the bs_get.shp in the same folder as the lyr-file.

How come this happens, when I have already imported the folder containing the source?

I added the data sources for the top 3 data, but doing so manually is very tedious.

Is there a way to select all missing data and repair data source at once?

I am a newbie at ArcGIS Pro, so I don't know anything about Python etc.

Also, these are shape files, because my university gave me an assignment involving these.

[image]

Comment: All because the layer file is in the same folder as the data does not mean the person who created it, did a proper job. The layer files data sources need to be set to relative. Which clearly they are not as you are experiencing broken links.

Answer (score 1):

To fix all click on the red exclamation mark and choose the correct shp file.
Doing so thru the exclamation will fix all the layers.